# Wishing for a spell

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

So I am a very new DM, I have been playing for like 2 months.

I was wondering if a person found a *scroll of wish*, could they use [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) for a spell to cast that their character would keep?

One of my players wished for an explosion spell and I'd want to know how to handle it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Wish spell scroll casts the Wish spell. Wish spell can be used to cast an 8th level (or lower) spell without the components it would normally require. If you use Wish this way, whatever spell you use is cast once.

Wish also states a list of particular effects like creating a valuable object, granting resistance, etc.

However, Wish does allow the caster to try and wish for virtually anything. If the caster wants to wish for a permanent "explosion" spell, they can try that. It's DMs call and duty to tell if that works.

From the Player's Handbook:

> State your wish to the DM as precisely as possible. The DM has great
>   latitude in ruling what occurs in such an instance; the greater the
>   wish, the greater the likelihood that something goes wrong. This spell
>   might simply fail, the effect you desire might only be partly
>   achieved, or you might suffer some unforeseen consequence as a result
>   of how you worded the wish.

Comment: Any advice for handling the specific wish in the question?

Comment: @seriousbri answering that would probably fall under opinion based.

Comment: Thank you for awnsering quickly

Comment: @SeriousBri I'd suggest considering the impact on letting that happen on your campaing. Would that completely ruin your plot ideas? The wish fails. Would that be fun, wether it forces you to change some ideas or not? Let it happen or roll a d20 to see if it works. You could also make it work in a completely different way, depending on the wording of the wish.